# How can I find out what is causing cmd.exe to be called on startup?

Tags: windows, boot, cmd.exe, autorun

Lately I've noticed that every time I boot up my computer a cmd window pops up trying to open some long-uninstalled software.

I was able to use Procmon to find out what the actual commands being executed are, but couldn't figure out a way to find out what program is calling cmd to execute them them and why.

I've tried using [this method](https://superuser.com/questions/1575059/how-to-tell-what-command-were-executed-by-cmd-exe-pop-up) involving gpedit which can log the creation of processes, but for some reason cmd.exe doesn't show up on the list (either as a parent or child).

Using Sysinternals Autorun also yields no entries for cmd.exe.

Comment: What were the actual comments being executed? It is highly unlikely that CMD is being called by the startup command you're seeing here. Rather, there is another exe being called that runs inside CMD, or that runs CMD, so you won't see CMD in AutoRuns. Look at AutoRuns again and isolate and understand EACH entry, starting with the entries in the LOGON tab, as this is the most likely location for any software you're seeing there.

Comment: Sorry, "commands", not "comments", in my above comment.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've checked the Autoruns, but there's nothing there I don't recognize. There is an entry for the program I'm talking about but it's disabled already.

Procexp says that the parent process is winlogon.exe.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of that uninstalled software the CMD is
trying to execute, search for it in the registry.
A good and quick search tool is
[RegScanner](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/regscanner.html).

If you find such entries they should be deleted, but very carefully.
You can ask us whether deleting them is safe.

You may also run the free
[CCleaner](https://www.ccleaner.com/)
to clean your registry. However, great care should be taken when it
marks entries for deletion.

I suggest to create a System Restore point before doing any registry
manipulations, to be able to easily undo them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the pointers, I'll try to search the registry and report back. Do you know of any specific keys I should look out for?